# Count and AVG in a single SQL Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, average

I am working through a course on database design. I am at a question where it wants me to make a query that takes the count of members that go out on call per month and display the average of that per month. The dates are in date/time format so I used datepart to pull the month only as the question requested. I am stumped at the part where it wants me to get the count then average it per month. I am fairly new to SQL and while I haven’t had too many issues, this one is stumping me. We are using MS Access and this is what I have so far.

```
SELECT
  DatePart("m",[Dispatch Date/Time]) AS [Month],
  Count([Responding Members].[Member ID]) AS [CountOfMember ID]
FROM [Responding Members]
INNER JOIN Calls ON [Responding Members].[Alarm #] = Calls.[Alarm #]
GROUP BY DatePart("m",[Dispatch Date/Time]);
```

I am not sure how to write it so that it could do both. The book is very bare bones on details. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

### Example:

```
[Calls]

[Alarm #] | [Dispatch Date/Time]
----------+---------------------
1         | 2020-01-01 10:00
2         | 2020-01-05 11:30
3         | 2020-02-02 15:50
```

```
[Responding Members]

[Alarm #] | [Member ID]
----------+------------
1         | 100
1         | 200
2         | 100
2         | 200
2         | 300
3         | 100
3         | 200
```

```
Expected result:

Month   | Calls | Avg members per call
--------+-------+---------------------
2020-01 | 2     | 2.5
2020-02 | 1     | 2
```

Comment: Your query is giving you, say, JAN = 10, FEB = 20 and you want to write a new query that gives you AVG = 15 instead?

Comment: On a side note: It suffices to count rows with `COUNT(*)` for your query. We use `COUNT(<something>)` when we explicitly want to count non-null occurences of something. You could `COUNT(Calls.[Alarm #])` so as to only count calls in case you want to turn the join into an outer join, which would otherwise count one instead of zero for members without calls.

Comment: It is having me take the calls table that has the date and other info and link it to a response table that then list the members assigned to each call.  Each call can have a different number of members. It wants me to take the total member's that go on call each month then avg each months count.

Comment: So, you want the number of calls and the average number of members per call for each month? Show sample table data and expected result, so we get the picture.

Comment: [link](https://ibb.co/JRcmwQt) Is the current query results. The formatting is the same as the expected query save for I need to now turn the count which my query came up with by adding the number of members that go on call each month and now I need to avg them by the number of members who go out per call that month. For example the result for  Jan or in the case of my query 1 Should give me 5.

Comment: Forgot to add the pictures to the two tables involved in the query here they are [link](https://ibb.co/cbyJzpT) and [link](https://ibb.co/NNjrhHh)

Comment: Don't use liks to images and don't put relevant information in the comments only. Edit your request instead and add the information as text. As you are new here, I've done that for you. Please look at the example I have given. Does that match your requirement? If not, click the edit link and correct the example.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

Query1: CountMembers

```
SELECT Format([DispatchDateTime],"yyyymm") AS YrMo, AlarmNumFK, Count(MemberID) AS CntMembers
FROM RespondingMembers INNER JOIN Calls ON RespondingMembers.AlarmNumFK = Calls.AlarmNum
GROUP BY Format([DispatchDateTime],"yyyymm"), AlarmNumFK;
```

Query2: CountAlarms

```
SELECT Format([DispatchDateTime],"yyyymm") AS YrMo, Count(Calls.AlarmNum) AS CntAlarms
FROM Calls
GROUP BY Format([DispatchDateTime],"yyyymm");
```

Query3:

```
SELECT CountMembers.YrMo, CntAlarms, Avg(CountMembers.CntMembers) AS AvgOfCntMembers
FROM CountAlarms INNER JOIN CountMembers ON CountAlarms.YrMo = CountMembers.YrMo
GROUP BY CountMembers.YrMo, CountAlarms.CntAlarms;
```

All in One:

```
SELECT CountMembers.YrMo, CntAlarms, Avg(CntMembers) AS AvgOfCntMembers
FROM 
    (SELECT Format([DispatchDateTime],"yyyymm") AS YrMo, Count(AlarmNum) AS CntAlarms
     FROM Calls
     GROUP BY Format([DispatchDateTime],"yyyymm")) AS CountAlarms 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT Format([DispatchDateTime],"yyyymm") AS YrMo, AlarmNumFK, Count(MemberID) AS CntMembers
     FROM RespondingMembers INNER JOIN Calls ON RespondingMembers.AlarmNumFK = Calls.AlarmNum
     GROUP BY Format([DispatchDateTime],"yyyymm"), AlarmNumFK) AS CountMembers 
ON CountAlarms.YrMo = CountMembers.YrMo
GROUP BY CountMembers.YrMo, CountAlarms.CntAlarms;
```

Note that I have not used spaces nor punctuation/special characters in naming convention.